# The Foundry Nuke – program a keystroke (backspace key)

Tags: python, keystroke, stereo-3d, backspace, nuke

So if you don't know The Foundry Nuke, I'm not sure if you can help me, so read on at the risk of your own time. If your still here, Awesome! Either you know it or think you can help anyway and are an awesome person.

Basically I'm using The Foundry Ocula inside Nuke and creating a Python script to automate some stuff for me. It goes ahead X frames, adds an analysis key, moves ahead frames, adds key, etc. What I want is to delete the error thresholded out key matches (which is usually done with the backspace key) but I can't find a script in Ocula to delete selected keys, nor can I find a way to Python script something like

```
nuke.keystroke('backspace')
```

to make Nuke react like someone just pressed the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key in the GUI. That code above is just an example of what I want... of course it's never that easy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try using the backspace character, `nuke.keystroke('\b')` or `nuke.keystroke('\x08')`.

Comment: well i know about '\b' but like i said in my question nuke.kesytroke() doesnt actually exist, thats just an exmaple of what im looking for (because last time i asked this question people gave me 19 ways to delete a character from a line which isnt what i need lol)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method but pay attention that after erasing all the keys in a range, in the `midtones.gain` knob there will be a `curve` value instead of default `1` (it's an abstract example):

```
nuke.animation("ColorCorrect1.midtones.gain", "erase", ("27", "53"))
```

Or for copying expression (generated for chosen keyframes) from handmade `userKnob` to `multiply` knob use this method:

```
nuke.animation("Grade9.multiply", "expression", ("Grade9.userKnob",))
```